# What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, overriding

I have a Wicket page class that sets the page title depending on the result of an abstract method.

```
public abstract class BasicPage extends WebPage {

    public BasicPage() {
        add(new Label("title", getTitle()));
    }

    protected abstract String getTitle();

}
```

NetBeans warns me with the message "Overridable method call in constructor", but what should be wrong with it? The only alternative I can imagine is to pass the results of otherwise abstract methods to the super constructor in subclasses. But that could be hard to read with many parameters.

Comment: I'm a .NET developer, but saw this one and was interested as to why it would warn against this because I do a similar thing at times in C#. This article seems to give an indication regarding why it is a warning:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215 So it's all to do with when and the order in which object hierarchy is inialised.

Comment: In C# we have the same problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

Comment: This reminds me to check if IntelliJ gives this warning...

Answer (score 513, accepted):

#### On invoking overridable method from constructors

Simply put, this is wrong because it unnecessarily opens up possibilities to *MANY* bugs. When the `@Override` is invoked, the state of the object may be inconsistent and/or incomplete.

A quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance, or else prohibit it*:

> There are a few more restrictions that a class must obey to allow inheritance. **Constructors must not invoke overridable methods**, directly or indirectly. If you violate this rule, program failure will result. The superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will be invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
public class ConstructorCallsOverride {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        abstract class Base {
            Base() {
                overrideMe();
            }
            abstract void overrideMe(); 
        }

        class Child extends Base {

            final int x;

            Child(int x) {
                this.x = x;
            }

            @Override
            void overrideMe() {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        new Child(42); // prints "0"
    }
}
```

Here, when `Base` constructor calls `overrideMe`, `Child` has not finished initializing the `final int x`, and the method gets the wrong value. This will almost certainly lead to bugs and errors.

#### Related questions

- [Calling an Overridden Method from a Parent-Class Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898422/calling-an-overridden-method-from-a-parent-class-constructor)
- [State of Derived class object when Base class constructor calls overridden method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330390/state-of-derived-class-object-when-base-class-constructor-calls-overridden-method)
- [Using abstract init() function in abstract class’s constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342784/using-abstract-init-function-in-abstract-classs-constructor)

#### See also

- [FindBugs - Uninitialized read of field method called from constructor of superclass](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#UR_UNINIT_READ_CALLED_FROM_SUPER_CONSTRUCTOR)

---

#### On object construction with many parameters

Constructors with many parameters can lead to poor readability, and better alternatives exist.

Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 2: Consider a builder pattern when faced with many constructor parameters*:

> Traditionally, programmers have used the *telescoping constructor* pattern, in which you provide a constructor with only the required parameters, another with a single optional parameters, a third with two optional parameters, and so on...

The telescoping constructor pattern is essentially something like this:

```
public class Telescope {
    final String name;
    final int levels;
    final boolean isAdjustable;

    public Telescope(String name) {
        this(name, 5);
    }
    public Telescope(String name, int levels) {
        this(name, levels, false);
    }
    public Telescope(String name, int levels, boolean isAdjustable) {       
        this.name = name;
        this.levels = levels;
        this.isAdjustable = isAdjustable;
    }
}
```

And now you can do any of the following:

```
new Telescope("X/1999");
new Telescope("X/1999", 13);
new Telescope("X/1999", 13, true);
```

You can't, however, currently set only the `name` and `isAdjustable`, and leaving `levels` at default. You can provide more constructor overloads, but obviously the number would explode as the number of parameters grow, and you may even have multiple `boolean` and `int` arguments, which would really make a mess out of things.

As you can see, this isn't a pleasant pattern to write, and even less pleasant to use (What does "true" mean here? What's 13?).

Bloch recommends using a builder pattern, which would allow you to write something like this instead:

```
Telescope telly = new Telescope.Builder("X/1999").setAdjustable(true).build();
```

Note that now the parameters are named, and you can set them in any order you want, and you can skip the ones that you want to keep at default values. This is certainly much better than telescoping constructors, especially when there's a huge number of parameters that belong to many of the same types.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 2: Consider a builder pattern when faced with many constructor parameters* ([excerpt online](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/EffectiveJava.aspx))

#### Related questions

- [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)
- [Is this a well known design pattern? What is its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637268/is-this-a-well-known-design-pattern-what-is-its-name/)

Comment: +1. Interesting. I wonder whether object initializers in C# render both telescoping constructors and the Builder pattern unnecessary.

Comment: @Johannes: In Java, instance initializer is executed at step 4, after superclass constructor at step 3, upon creation of new instances http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5 ; I'm not sure if that addresses your comment though.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a special handling for enums as this seem to work fine????

Comment: For the telescope constructor, I would not hard-code the defaults for every constructor. Store those in static constants at least, or in a file...

Comment: That said, it's too bad Java doesn't do a 2 phase initialization: 1st pass for method *definitions*, 2nd pass for execution of constructor.  Now I gotta write *more* code for some factory-factory pattern or other.  Bleh.  All I wanted was to set some default data from a pure function that could be swapped in a subclass, or updated between construct and use.

Comment: Android engineers be aware: android view's overridable method invalidate() is sometimes called in view's constructor.

Comment: FYI: the quoted sentence "If you violate this rule, program failure will result." is an outright lie. It is, however, somewhat more likely to result in the future.

Comment: @immibis Sometimes the truth won't get the message across. I imagine a 'gentle warning' could result in more people thinking they know what they're doing (when they don't) and just do it.

Comment: Stepping through the Java `<init>` code with a debugger used to be a _surreal_ experience.  My simple view is that (all) daughter-class(-es) are NOT initialised at the time-of parent constructor execution.  _However_ there are work-arounds.  My favourite is to have a `private static` method which you _may_ call from the constuctor, that can then call your `@Override` method because the `<init>` is complete at that time.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: How is builder better compared to calling constructor and then set of setters?

Comment: Not allowing to invoke overridable methods from a constructor hinders the implementation of a template-like factory pattern, which is described here [Factory Pattern in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java) .

Answer (score 63):

Here's an example which helps to understand this:

```
public class Main {
    static abstract class A {
        abstract void foo();
        A() {
            System.out.println("Constructing A");
            foo();
        }
    }

    static class C extends A {
        C() { 
            System.out.println("Constructing C");
        }
        void foo() { 
            System.out.println("Using C"); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C(); 
    }
}
```

If you run this code, you get the following output:

```
Constructing A
Using C
Constructing C
```

You see? `foo()` makes use of C before C's constructor has been run. If `foo()` requires C to have a defined state (i.e. the constructor *has finished*), then it will encounter an undefined state in C and things might break. And since you can't know in A what the overwritten `foo()` expects, you get a warning.

Answer (score 12):

Invoking an overridable method in the constructor allows subclasses to subvert the code, so you can't guarantee that it works anymore. That's why you get a warning.

In your example, what happens if a subclass overrides `getTitle()` and returns null ?

To "fix" this, you can use a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead of a constructor, it's a common pattern of objects instanciation.

Comment: returning `null` is a general problem breaking many interfaces.

Comment: returning null is a special problem when it happens in overridden methods which get called by the super constructor.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example that reveals the **logical problems** that can occur when calling an overridable method in the super constructor.

```
class A {

    protected int minWeeklySalary;
    protected int maxWeeklySalary;

    protected static final int MIN = 1000;
    protected static final int MAX = 2000;

    public A() {
        setSalaryRange();
    }

    protected void setSalaryRange() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }

    public void pr() {
        System.out.println("minWeeklySalary: " + minWeeklySalary);
        System.out.println("maxWeeklySalary: " + maxWeeklySalary);
    }
}

class B extends A {

    private int factor = 1;

    public B(int _factor) {
        this.factor = _factor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setSalaryRange() {
        this.minWeeklySalary = MIN * this.factor;
        this.maxWeeklySalary = MAX * this.factor;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B(2);
    b.pr();
}
```

The result would actually be:

minWeeklySalary: 0

maxWeeklySalary: 0

This is because the constructor of class B first calls the constructor of class A, where the overridable method inside B gets executed. But inside the method we are using the instance variable **factor** which has **not yet been initialized** (because the constructor of A has not yet finished), thus factor is 0 and not 1 and definitely not 2 (the thing that the programmer might think it will be). Imagine how hard would be to track an error if the calculation logic was ten times more twisted.

I hope that would help someone.

Answer (score 4):

If you call methods in your constructor that subclasses override, it means you are less likely to be referencing variables that don’t exist yet if you divide your initialization logically between the constructor and the method.

Have a look on this sample link http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215

Answer (score 3):

I certainly agree that there are cases where **it is better not to call some methods from a constructor**.

Making them **private** takes away all doubt: [*"You shall not pass"*](https://youtu.be/mJZZNHekEQw?t=81).

#### However, what if you DO want to keep things open.

It's **not just the access modifier** that is the real problem, as I tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843825/why-are-member-objects-initialized-after-the-super-classs-constructor/69281826#69281826). To be completely honest, `private` is a clear showstopper where `protected` usually will still allow a (harmful) workaround.

A more general advice:

- don't start threads from your constructor
- don't read files from your constructor
- don't call APIs or services from your constructor
- don't load data from a database from your constructor
- don't parse json or xml documents from your constructor

Don't do so (in)directly from your constructor. That includes doing any of these actions from a private/protected function which is called by the constructor.

**Calling an `start()` method from your constructor could certainly be a red flag.**

Instead, you should provide a **public** `init()`, `start()` or `connect()` method. And leave the responsibility to the consumer.

Simply put, you want to **separate** the moment of "**preparation**" from the "**ignition**".

- if a constructor can be extended then it shouldn't self-ignite.
- If it self-ignites then it risks being launched before being fully constructed.
- After all, some day more preparation could be added in the constructor of a subclass. And you don't have any control over the order of execution of the constructor of a super class.

*PS: consider implementing the [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface along with it.*

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of Wicket: This is the very reason why I asked the Wicket 
devs to add support for an explicit two phase component initialization process in the framework's lifecycle of constructing a component i.e.

1. Construction - via constructor
2. Initialization - via onInitilize (after construction when virtual methods work!)

There was quite an active debate about whether it was necessary or not (it fully  is necessary IMHO) as this link demonstrates http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/VOTE-WICKET-3218-Component-onInitialize-is-broken-for-Pages-td3341090i20.html)

The good news is that the excellent devs at Wicket did end up introducing two phase initialization (to make the most aweseome Java UI framework even more awesome!) so with Wicket you can do all your post construction initialization in the onInitialize method that is called by the framework automatically if you override it - at this point in the lifecycle of your component its constructor has completed its work so virtual methods work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for Wicket it's better to call `add` method in the `onInitialize()` (see [components lifecycle](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/componentLifecycle.html)) :

```
public abstract class BasicPage extends WebPage {

    public BasicPage() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        add(new Label("title", getTitle()));
    }

    protected abstract String getTitle();
}
```