# Is there a way for a Scala base class to get informed when all the derived classes have been constructed? (guess not)

Tags: scala

First: why on Earth am I asking this?

I'd like to have a working 'invariant' check system with my classes, and this would allow a nice way to make it happen. Each level could provide their invariants (if any) and the base class would execute them at the end of the construction chain.

Similar question on Java: [Running a method after the constructor of any derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906958/running-a-method-after-the-constructor-of-any-derived-class)

Comment: Can you clarify the mechanism you are looking for. What are "all derived classes". My interpretation is you have type `A` and `B <: A`, and `C <: A`, and `D <: B`. So do you want to wait till *at some point at runtime there are instances of each of* `B`, `C`, and `D`. Or do you want to wait for *one particular instantiation*, e.g. for the constructor of `D` to complete?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: [Running code after subclass initialization](http://rogach-scala.blogspot.ru/2012/05/running-code-after-subclass.html)